# Is there any way to change the text size (font size) of specific blocks when you using asciidoc?

Tags: text-size, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I need your help.

Now I am using AsciiDoc and AsciiDoctor to create some manuals.

I want texts smaller on some specific blocks, for example wide table, wide list, and so on, but not want main texts smaller.
Especially I need to make texts of wide tables smaller as my customer requests so.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mention lists and tables...
About lists, it can't be done as stated in [AsciiDoctor Documentation](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#attribute-limitations):

> Unsupported
> Complex AsciiDoc markup is not permitted in attribute values, such as:
>
> - lists
> - multiple paragraphs
> - other whitespace-dependent markup types

As you can see, there it mentions multiple paragraphs, so while @EhmKah answer is a correct way to set a custom styling block, it won't be rendered as expected in a table/list as it's multi-paragraph.

The **Built-in CSS class syntax** is the way to go `[small]#any phrases#`
*But* in order to make this work in a table, you must set the cell type with a **specifier** in this case, the *AsciiDoc specifier* denoted by **a**
This means the cell (or column) will render supported AsciiDoc statements, attributes, etc.

Here's a working example:

```
[frame="none",grid="none"]
|====
a| image::images\logo.png[] a|[.small]#Autor: {author}#
|====
```

If you have tons of rows/columns, you don't have to manually apply the `a` to all of them. You can set the columns you need this behavior this way:

```
[cols="1a,2a",frame="none",grid="none"]
|====
| image::images\logo.png[] |[.small]#Autor: {author}#
|====
```

You can check its documentation for more about [Column Formatting](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#cols-format) and you can check the *Rendered table with variable widths and alignments* sub section for more about AsciiDoc (`a`) and other specifiers.

Comment: thanks for nice detailed answer, very helpful. (and sorry for my late marking answered, I was mis-remembered that I'd already set)

Answer (score 3):

**`docinfo.html` + `--attribute docinfo=shared`**

You can drop your CSS modifications into a file called `docinfo.html`:

```
<style>
/* Your custom CSS. */
</style>
```

and then build with:

```
asciidoctor --attribute docinfo=shared README.adoc
```

and that makes Asciidoctor 2.0.10 place `docinfo.html` at the bottom of the `<head>` element.

So you can override most of the default Asciidoctor style from there.

Then it's just a matter of understanding the generated HTML and previous style definitions to override them.

For `image` specifically, see also: [How to set a custom image height for an image in Asciidoctor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63464732/how-to-set-image-height-in-asciidoctor)

Answer (score 3):

When you use a theme file, you can add a role to it like this:

```
role:
  mycustomfont:
    font-color: #333
    font-size:  10
```

Now you can reference your newly created role right from your table cell:

```
a|[.mycustomfont]# some text #
```

Comment: very good idea but could you provide fully working example?

Answer (score 0):

I read something about

- [small] and [%autofit] option https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/issues/185 I never needed it so maybe you give it a try.

example-code

```
[small]
----
should be rendered in smaller font.
----

[%autofit]
----
really long text that doesn't want to fit on a single line with the default font size, so we'll make it shrink to fit.
----
```

Comment: Although I tried `[small]` and `[%autofit]` for table blocks, they couldn't work...  

And about `[small]`, the way you wrote didn't work at all. `[small]#any phrases#` became smaller font.

Comment: @macoril could you please repeat your comment as an answer and mark your question as answered?

Comment: About the answer, that's a custom style block and about @marcoil comment that's a Built-in CSS class syntax. Both are correct but to be able to use these in a table, please take a look at my answer.